# RoR onchange check condition before calling remote_function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using remote_function call

onchange before calling remote_function i want to check the condition

iam using code written below

-Add Name-", 
       :onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => :name, :action => :create_name})
    %>

here i want to check if (escape(value) == -1) then call remote_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want do the check here ? You may do check inside yoiur `remote_function` 
for example

```
if (escape(value) == -1){
  //do something
}
```

or

```
if (escape(value) == -1){
  //do something
}else{
  //do nothing or do something else
}
```

edits

example helper

```
def my_remote_function(var)
  s = ""
  if (var == "false")
    s = "alert('java')"
  end 
  s
end

 <%= select_tag "people", "<option>David</option><option>Bruse</option>", :onchange=>my_remote_function("true")
```

Comment: i tried using if condition inside remote function its not working..
can u  please show me how to use if conditon in this code,

:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => :name, :action => :create_name}) %>

Comment: :onchange accepts string as an argument so you may write some helper method which accepts "value" as a param and returns some string or nothing or you may write ruby core inside string